# Changing JSON field height (on ng-admin)

Tags: ng-admin

I have simple web form to collect data from a user. In my particular case i'm making use of the JSON field to collect a custom data structure.

Is it possible to change the height/size of a JSON field?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS rule to your stylesheet:

```
.CodeMirror {
  height: auto;
}
```

Now the JSON edition field widget will match the height of the serialized JSON!